# How to use the react spring hook with react. Basic code not working

Tags: reactjs, react-spring, react-animated

THe animation just doesnt work with this code. What am I doing wrong?

```
import React from 'react'
import { useSpring, animated } from 'react-spring'


function Comp1() {
  const props = useSpring({ opacity: 1, from: { opacity: 0 } })
  return (
      <animated.div style={c1Style}>

        <h1 style={{ color: "white" }}>Component 1</h1>
        <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted
        by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.
        The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less
        normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here,
         content here', making it look like readable English. </p>

      </animated.div>
  )
}

const c1Style = {
  background: 'steelblue',
  color: 'white',
  padding: '1.5rem'
}

export default Comp1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add you spring animation `props` to animation.div style as well:

```
function Comp1() {
  const props = useSpring({ opacity: 1, from: { opacity: 0 } })
  return (
    <animated.div style={{...c1Style, ...props }}>
      <h1 style={{ color: "white" }}>Component 1</h1>
      <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted
      by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.
      The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less
      normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here,
       content here', making it look like readable English. </p>
    </animated.div>
  )
}
```

[image: spring-animation]